# Angular ngModel value is shown but it is empty

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, model

`ngModel` is shown the value. But it's still empty as required validate detects as it's empty. **It works when I add an empty space and after the value.**

Code to get the name

```
<div (click)="getName(item.name)"></div>
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.name" value="{{name}}">
```

Component.ts

```
name: string;
data: Data

getName(nm) {
 this.name = nm;
}
```

Comment: Where is `data.name` in TS file?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just enough

`<input matInput [(ngModel)]="name">`

You should not use both `[(ngModel)]` and value properties together. As `[]` of `[(ngModel)]` already define the value of the input. So you can use `(ngModel)` and `value`/ `[value]`/`[(ngModel)]`

Comment: updated the question. Data is the model I need to by the value of 'name'

Answer (score 0):

What is `data.name` that is bound to ngModel?

I think you need not use the value attribute
Bind the `name` component variable to the ngModel like below

```
<div (click)="getName('hello')">Click</div>

<input matInput [(ngModel)]="name"> {{name}}
```

In your component,

```
name: string;

getName(nm) {
 this.name = nm;
}
```

Hit the click button, you will see that the input gets value 'hello'

Comment: updated the question. **Data** is the model I need to by the value of 'name'

Comment: Sorry, I did  not understand, so Onclick you want to update data.name? if so, then  in the getName(nm) method modify this.name to this.data.name

Answer (score 0):

[(ngModel)] removed from anguler 7 its better use formcontrall
https://next.angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel